# Again I can not understand 'take on'

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

Again I can not understand 'take on'. Is it a phrasal verb or a verb and preposition and what does it mean here?

> Politics here **takes on** an ethical necessity and ambition.

Comment: It's a phrasal verb. It means "assumes" or "adopts."

Comment: Phrasal verbs in English map to separable verbs in German where it's a single word: annehmen -> nimmt an (takes on)

Comment: 'Acquire' is another equivalent. My father's shirt took on a reddish hue when the plastic ketchup bottle burst.

Comment: [Here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20on) is its Merriam-Webster entry.